# Why does the if argument in Excel VBA not work?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm writing a simple code in Excel VBA that takes 2 dates from the user and calculate the average of the price values between those 2 dates from a CSV file. It does it by 2 for loops for each date which contains an if condition for checking weather the input value is equal to each date value in the file.
**But strangely the first if condition does not work, although the second one is working properly.
I checked it line by line, there is no difference between 2 loops.**

The dates column in the CSV file is the "A" and the prices are in the "B" column.

```vb
Public Sub average()`
Dim date1, date2 As Date
Dim x, n As Integer

date1 = InputBox("Enter the initial date")
date2 = InputBox("Enter the final date")

Range("A5000").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
n = Selection.Row

For x = 2 To n
    Range("A" & x).Select
    If date1 = Range("A" & x).Value Then
        Range("A" & x).Select
        Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
        row1 = Selection.Row
        Exit For
    End If
Next x

For x = 2 To n
    Range("A" & x).Select
    If date2 = Range("A" & x).Value Then
        Range("A" & x).Select
        Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
        row2 = Selection.Row
        Exit For
    End If
Next x
```

Comment: `there is no difference between 2 loops` - there is. In the first loop you are using `date1 As Variant`, in the second `date2 As Date`. Your `date1` contains a string in some format, rather than a binary date value.

Comment: The entire contents of your `If` within your loop can be switched with `row1 = x` and then `Exit For`. You should try to avoid using `Select` and `Selection`.

Comment: What format are you entering the date d/m/y or m/d/y ?

Comment: It is solved. as @Gserg said the problem was that I didn't explicitly designate date1 as Date, I thought when you type two variables in one line before " as Date", they are equally defined as Date but it seems they are not.  Thank you.